# uploading image with express js in openshift and getting the url of uploaded image

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, openshift

I am working on user profile in express where i need to upload user image. i have searched a lot but didn't get much info about this.

so this is so far i have done.
My profile view code:-

```
 <form method="post" name="profileform" class="profileform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="UserProfilePicture">Profile Picture:</label>
     <input type="file" class="form-control" id="UserProfilePicture" class="UserProfilePicture disbalefield" name="file"  placeholder="Click to add Profile Pic"></div> 
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" class="userprofilesubmit" id="userprofilesubmit" />
    </form>
```

and this is my server.js code

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR+'/uploads'));
app.use(express.limit('5mb'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/profile', function(req, res){
if(!req.session.logged_in){
    res.redirect('/login');
}
console.log("dsadsa");
  // Get the temporary location of the file
var tmp_path = req.files.file.path;
// Set where the file should actually exists - in this case it is in the "images" directory.
var target_path = process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR + '/uploads/' + req.files.file.name;


// Move the file from the temporary location to the intended location
fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }

    // Delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files.
    fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }
        //
        console.log("reached");
            res.send("uploaded");
    });
});


});
```

Sorry about the indentations. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Would the url be the "target_path"? if so, if there's not an err, you could then save it to the user after a successful fs.rename.

Comment: i am getting internal server error and where can i check my image if i open the files from filezilla?

Comment: We need way more details. At least the server logs and the exact error and also the expected and the actual behavior.

Comment: Hey Farid...Error is ENONET, rename '/tmp/431865-n9mkt3.png'

Comment: changed my code a little bit. removed the fs.unlink function and pasted my console.log and res.send in rename function.

Also do i need to create a upload folder in app-root/data directory as i have read somewhere that Openshift will automatically create it?

Comment: okk i sorted out with the issue. was problem with temp directory and original directory of openshift.